# Internal workflow of MasterPages

Tags: .net, asp.net, architecture, master-pages

Can anyone provide me any documentation or link for internal workflow and architecture of Master Pages in asp.net ?

Answer (score 1):

[Nested ASP.NET Master Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546988/internal-workflow-of-masterpages)

[Walkthrough: Using Nested Master Pages in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb547109.aspx)

[Nested Master Pages](http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials/nested-master-pages-cs)

---

[ASP.NET Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx)

[ASP.NET Master Pages Tutorials](http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials)

Comment: @Saurabh: Could you be more specific ??